Bash variable ${FOO//\''/|'} behaviour - why does this work?
I'm confused about Bash's handling of ${x//\''/|'} vs zsh's ${x//'/|'}.
I wanted to wrap Teamcity's 'block start/end' directives fairly nicely for a Bash script, so I'd only have to supply tc_block_start with the block's name, and making it handle embedded ' character escaping.
I have ended up with this (without block nesting for simplicity, and with "#""#..." to avoid set -x confusing Teamcity's message scanner):
#!/bin/bash

tc_block_start() {
  [ -n "${tc_block:-}" ] && tc_block_end && echo "WARNING: tc_start: Automatically closed last block"
  tc_block="${1//\''/|'}"
  echo "#""#teamcity[blockOpened name='$tc_block']"
}

tc_block_end() {
  : "${tc_block:?unset - mismatched tc_end, apparently}"
  echo "#""#teamcity[blockClosed name='$tc_block']"
  tc_block=""
}

tc_block_start "Fred's cat"
echo stuff
tc_block_end

But... golly gee, I don't understand why bash needs two apostrophes with the first escaped - ${1//\''/|'} - instead of just the one (optionally escaped) apostrophe which zsh understands: ${1//\'/|'}or ${1//'/|'}.
Can someone explain this?
I recognise quote-removal is implicated, but I'm having trouble making sense of it in detail and I don't like relying on magic.

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parameter-expansion/info or man --pager='less -p "Parameter Expansion"' bash

Please get rid of all the irrelevant text and code from your question and simply provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates just the problem you're asking for help with (which sounds like it might just be about doing something like foo="Fred's cat"; echo "${foo//\'/|\'}") and all the teamcity stuff and functions are irrelevant but I can't tell if you're trying to replace 's with |s or put |s in front of 's or something else).
